# Are there algorithms to adapt anchor points on polygons?

Tags: graph, geometry, 2d, computational-geometry

A line L is to be drawn from an arbitrary point P to one of the segments of a convex polygon Y (2D).

My question is, how one would calculate an anchor point, in a way that when moving the polygon the anchor point can be adapted in a smooth manner?

Imagine a polygon on your screen, a line from a distant point aims the centre of Y and stops at the first segment it reaches.

I am searching for a method which does not necessary aims to the centre but rather looks pleasing to the human eye.

Any paper, algorithms or keywords in this regard would be helpful.

Comment: Is the polygon convex, star-shaped, or can it be self-intersecting, is it allowed to have holes in it?

Comment: "looks pleasing to the human eye": hem, can you be more precise ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why aiming at the center wouldn't be a good solution.

Alternatively, use the shortest distance from the point to the polygon outline, which will fall either on a vertex or on a side.